# xcopy include folder

Tags: batch-file

This should be a simple question, but I haven't been able to find an answer.  I'd like to copy Folder (not just the contents) to the Desktop.  Everything I've tried takes just the contents of the folder.
I've tried what I have below, but the contents are still only copied.

```
xcopy C:\Users\user\Folder C:\Users\user\Desktop /E
```

Comment: `xcopy C:\Users\user\Folder C:\Users\user\Desktop\FOLDER /E` ?

Comment: because it copy the contents not the folder itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xcopy C:\Users\user\Folder C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder /E /I
```

What about this?

Comment: This seems to work. So you have to actually add the name "Folder" (which does not exist in the destiny one). mmmm