# copy a whole folder (not just contents) into another folder in cmd terminal

Tags: windows, cmd, copy, directory

I would like to copy an entire folder to other folder. NOT JUST the content of that folder.
For that I would like to do it in the CMD terminal.

FolderOriging1

```
/---folderA
/---folderB
/---folderC
```

FolderDesteny

```
/---empty
```

Result that I like:

```
FolderDesteny
/---folderA
```

(with `folderA` including all the files and folders and subfolders)
I saw several posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554764/xcopy-include-folder) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510929/copy-folder-into-another-folder) for instance
They all end up copying the contents of folder A, but not the folder itself.

for instance:

```
xcopy C:\folderA C:\folderB /E
```

this copies the contents of folder A to folder B

```
xcopy C:\folderA C:\folderB\folderA /E
```

Does not work neither

Other modifiers like the one pointed out in the above posted link do not work neither:

```
xcopy C:\folderA C:\folderB /E /i
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the Super User question: [Commmand line command to copy entire directory (including directory folder) to another directory](https://superuser.com/questions/206036/commmand-line-command-to-copy-entire-directory-including-directory-folder-to-a). The Super User question contains multiple answers that offer solutions using `xcopy` and other commands.

Comment: Your variant `xcopy C:\folderA C:\folderB\folderA /E` works but it asks you whether the destination is a file or a directory; to specify it is a directory simply add the `/I` option; alternatively append a `\ `to the destination...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `xcopy C:\folderA C:\folderB\folderA /E` does not work is because `folderA` does not exist in `C:\folderB`. Which is evident from the directory structure in your question:

```
/folderA
/folderB
/folderC
```

You need to use the `/I` switch to create the directory if it does not exist. So your command should be:

```
xcopy C:\folderA C:\folderB\folderA /E /I
```

Note that Microsoft also advises to use the `/O`, `/X`, `/H` and `/K` switches with `xcopy` when you want to retain the folder's permissions. There effects follow:

```
/H - Copies hidden and system files also.
/K - Copies attributes. Typically, Xcopy resets read-only attributes.
/O - Copies file ownership and ACL information.
/X - Copies file audit settings (implies /O)
```

Source: [HOW TO: Copy a Folder to Another Folder and Retain its Permissions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323007/how-to-copy-a-folder-to-another-folder-and-retain-its-permissions)

If you would like more information about copying a folder and its contents to another folder using `xcopy` and alternatives to using `xcopy`, then check out this Super User question: [Commmand line command to copy entire directory (including directory folder) to another directory](https://superuser.com/questions/206036/commmand-line-command-to-copy-entire-directory-including-directory-folder-to-a).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo d|xcopy /E "c:\folderA" "C:\folderB\folderA"
```

The `d` will serves as the interactive choice `d` for folder.

Or just

```
xcopy /E "c:\folderA" "C:\folderB\folderA\"
```